# How to stop a bootstrap data target to open based on condition

Tags: angularjs, html, bootstrap-4

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton1"  name="submitButton1"
        class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light"
        ng-click =  "validateAndSaveData('upload')"
        value="Upload Documents" data-target="#myModal1"
        data-toggle="modal">Upload
</button>
```

I am adding a function to validate the fields of form and i want the datatarget to be triggered if all the conditions are satisfied.

```
$scope.validateAndSaveData= function(initiatorName,emailId,actionType){

    if( angular.isUndefined($scope.requestType)){
                    alert("Kindly Select Request Type");
                    $('#requestType').focus();
                    return false;
    }
}
```

If this function returns false that means the model should not be triggered.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and AngularJS is asking for grief. Consider using the [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directives, Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can trigger the modal via javascript

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton1"  name="submitButton1" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click =  "validateAndSaveData('upload')"  value="Upload Documents" data-target="#myModal1">Upload</button>
```

and

```
$scope.validateAndSaveData= function(initiatorName,emailId,actionType){


                if( angular.isUndefined($scope.requestType)){
                                alert("Kindly Select Request Type");
                                $('#requestType').focus();
                } else {
                     var id = $('#requestType').data('target');
                     $(id).modal('show'); 
                }
}
```

Comment: So you are telling to remove data-target and call directly from script.

Comment: Yes, it could not be simpler